# spring web application error 406 on jackson decoding

Tags: spring, jackson

I tried to add a restful web service to my web application, and came across the following problem:

Whenever I register my @RestController which contains one request mapping returning an object with jackson, my static resource handling stops to work. The restful web service works just fine, but whenever my site tries to load e.g. an image or a stylesheet, the server throws the following error:

```
Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not find acceptable representation
```

Comment: Edit: I use public void `addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)` method on WebMvsConfigAdapter to register resource handlers, so I can not define any options like Accept on a RequestHandler.

Comment: Also it seems a bit weird, that creating a @RestController modifies the behaviour of the static content serving, which is not related at all (I think).

Answer (score 0):

406 error means the request content is considered Not Acceptable by the server.
Try to

- remove the Accept header or
- add headers="Accept=*/*" to the @RequestMapping annotations.

Comment: I can not modify the request mapping, because I use the `public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)` method on WebMvsConfigAdapter, which allows me to register resource handlers. I can not see a way of defining options for a RequestMapping.